# Webpack __webpack_require__ different indexes for the same project in different bundles

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular project with 3 projects in my build.

Main, Core and Content

Core exposes a navigation service and also provides that navigation service.
Main injects the navigation service into one of its components.
Content also injects the navigation service into one of its components.

The project builds but will not run, when it runs the Main component fails as it cannot find the provider that was setup in core.

When I investigate the javascript that webpack compiled I see that Core has different indexes in Main and Content.

const Core_1 = **webpack_require**(1);
const Core_1 = **webpack_require**(2);

This is making me believe that the provider is failing because it believes that Core is a different module.

When I look at Angular Core it is always the same index in each of my files.

How can I get webpack to recognize that it is the same core module in each and have the indexes correctly coincide.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using local packages and copying the node modules directory of the local npm package to the main package, this was causing there to be multiple copies of the core package in the build so it was actually different packages so the indexes were different.